# What's the meaning of $\tilde{y}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In *Linear Algebra*  by *Liesen, J. and Mehrmann, V.*, the following notation is used:

[image]

This chapter is about Maps in Set Theory. The authors explain the meaning of each symbol, nevertheless, they missed this one. I did some research in [Wolfram Math World](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tilde.html), but none of the examples of how the tilde is used throughout math seems promising for this example (at least none that I can make sense of).

Here is a screenshot of where it is first used in the book:

[image]

Comment: The author is just using $\tilde y$ as the name of a quantity. We tend to run out of letters in math, you know. This is kind of like asking what $x$ means. It's just a name we use sometimes.

Comment: You've gotten valid answer to your question, but I'll just add that I think it's slightly odd/unusual notation, and I'd be a bit confused too if I saw it. If someone uses a variable, like $y$, that ranges over a set $Y$, then I think the most common way to designate particular values of that variable is with subscripts, i.e. $y_0$, $y_1$, $y_2$, etc..

Comment: perhaps the author did not want the reader to confuse $\tilde y$ with the $y$ in the previous sentence

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: That's a possibility. Now that I think about it more, I've realized that my expectation when I see a tilde is that it is a transform of some previously existing quantity, so $\tilde y$ is something like a Fourier transform of, or some kind of conjugate of, $y$. I'd expect an author to use primes or subscripts ($y'$, $y_1$) to indicate a new quantity that is of the same "type" as $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They said "Let $\tilde{y} \in Y$ be given". This means they're just picking an arbitrary element of the set $Y$. One can just as well say "Let $\xi \in Y$ be given", or "Let $\zeta \in Y$ be given" or "Let $\ddot{\smile} \in Y$ be given". It's just a symbol and a name which we temporarily give to the arbitrarily chosen element of the set $Y$.

For example, I can write the bottom of the proof as:

> Let $\ddot{\smile} \in Y$ be given, then
>   \begin{align}
> (f \circ g)(\ddot{\smile}) &= f(g(\ddot{\smile})) = f(x_{\ddot{\smile}}) = \ddot{\smile}
> \end{align}
>   Hence $f \circ g = \text{Id}_Y$.

From a mathematical perspective, this is a perfectly meaningful proof, because from a purely mathematical perspective, what's to stop you from calling something a smiley-face? Aboslutely nothing at all! (of course, in practice no one actually writes a smiley face for elements of a set...)